# C# Custom list duplicate values based on a property

Tags: c#

I have a custom list class let say,

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Weight{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I am adding records to it like this,

```
 List<Fruit> Fruits= new List<Fruit>();

 //some foreach loop 
 Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
 fruit.Name = ...;
 fruit.Size = ...;
 fruit.Weight = ...;

 Fruits.Add(fruit);
```

**What I want ?**

I want to make changes to `Public Fruit Class` in a way that it checks if any of fruit in custom list has already has same weight then just ignore it and continue e.g. don't add it to the list.

I would prefer doing it without changing foreach loop logic

Comment: _" not allowed to change foreach loop logic"_ So what can you use ?

Comment: You should just use a set with custom `IEqualityComparer<Fruit>` passed in.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek While I think that would *work*, I do think in this case it would break the semantic meaning of the `IEqualityComparer` interface.

Comment: What is your "custom list"? Where the list is being used? You can use List.Any to check and then continue the loop.

Comment: Use a LINQ Or simpler, use a some kind of a Dictionary, with weight as a key.

Comment: Can you not have a class something like `FruitList` which derives from `List<Fruit>` and have the logic you are asking in that class?

Comment: LINQ would help you to implement tasks like this in one line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use LINQ `.Any()` - Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

```
if (!Fruits.Any(f => fruit.Weight != null && f.Weight == fruit.Weight))
   Fruits.Add(fruit);
```

Answer (score 1):

If duplicate weights are not allowed i would use a [`HashSet<Fruit>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) with a custom `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class FruitWeightComparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit>
{
    public bool Equals(Fruit x, Fruit y)
    {
        if(x == null || y== null) return false;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        return x.Weight == y.Weight;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Fruit obj)
    {
        return obj.Weight == null ? 0 : obj.Weight.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the [`HashSet` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx) with this comparer:

```
HashSet<Fruit> Fruits = new HashSet<Fruit>(new FruitWeightComparer());
// ...
bool notInSet = Fruits.Add(fruit);
```

[`HashSet.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns true if the item could be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it at insert time by simply not inserting already existing fruit

```
if (!myFruits.Any(f => f.Weight == newFruit.Weight))
   myFruits.Add(newFruit);
```

If you can't manipulate the insertion logic you can make a custom list that wraps a normal `List<T>` and changes the behavior of `Add` like in the above example:

```
public class FruitsWithDistinctWeightList : IEnumerable<Fruit>
{  
    private List<Fruit> internalList;

    ... // Constructor etc.

    public void Add(Fruit fruit)
    {
       if (!internalList.Any(f => f.Weight == fruit.Weight))
         internalList.Add(fruit);
    }       

    ... // Further impl of IEnumerable<Fruit> or IList<Fruit>
}
```

You could also use some existing collection that does not allow duplicate items. For example some hash based collection such as `HashSet<Fruit>`:

```
var fruitsWithDistinctWeight = new HashSet<Fruit>(new FruitWeightComparer());
```

Where you'd use a comparer that says fruits with equal weight are equal:

```
public class FruitWeightComparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit>
{
   public bool Equals(Fruit one, Fruit two)
   {
        return one.Weight == two.Weight;
   }

   public int GetHashCode(Fruit item)
   {
        return one.Weight.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Note that a `HashSet<T>` is not ordered like a list is. Note that all of the code above for simplicity assumes that the Weight field is set. If you have public setters on your class (i.e. no guarantees of this) you would have to change appropriately.